# Issues with using the videojs-language-switch plugin for video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I'm trying to use the plugin for switching the video language for video.js found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-language-switch and on the video.js website:

However, I cannot even make the simplest example given in the repo worm,
In the browser I get this error:

```
TypeError: videojs.MenuItem is undefined
Error: plugin "languageSwitch" does not exist
```

here is my code:

```
HTML:
 <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
<source src="https://cdn-film-http.twig-world.com/TWG00604/2012-02-22/h264-800/b5498f3a034547c3b2a1d4e5c825c6f1.mp4" type='video/mp4' name='English'>

<p class="vjs-no-js">
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
  <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
</p>
```

```
javascript:
  var player = videojs('my-video');

player.languageSwitch({
languages: [
  {
    name: 'English',
    sources: [
      {
        src: 'https://cdn-film-http.twig-world.com/TWG00604/2012-02-22/h264-800/b5498f3a034547c3b2a1d4e5c825c6f1.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        res: 'Medium'
      },
      {
        src: 'https://cdn-film-http.twig-world.com/TWG00604/2012-02-22/WebM-800/227a2a4cceb23b1605111bc7797b9bd6.webm',
        type: 'video/webm',
        res: 'Medium'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Portuguese',
    sources: [
      {
        src: 'https://cdn-film-http.twig-world.com/BRPTTWG00604/2013-12-19/h264-800/87558365664a78b2abdc2d915024dc9d.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        res: 'Medium'
      },
      {
        src: 'https://cdn-film-http.twig-world.com/BRPTTWG00604/2013-12-19/WebM-800/79ba5f114f2cb800abe153deb8fee242.webm',
        type: 'video/webm',
        res: 'Medium'
      }
    ]
  }
]
});
```

I put it here:
https://codepen.io/coucous/pen/ZwELEO

With the following CDN:

```
https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamoliver/VJS-language-switch/master/videojs.language-switch.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.4.2/video.min.js
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamoliver/VJS-language-switch/master/videojs.language-switch.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CodePen, the issue is that raw.githubusercontent.com does not set the content-type header correctly (intentionally). You see an error like this in the console:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamoliver/VJS-language-switch/master/videojs.language-switch.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Try using an alternative URL, e.g.

- https://unpkg.com/videojs-language-switch@1.2.0/dist/videojs-language-switch.js
- https://unpkg.com/videojs-language-switch@1.2.0/dist/videojs-language-switch.css

Comment: Thanks, this works, also, I realized that I was using the old repo which was not working on the latest version of video.js